# What does movement in time dimension means?

Tags: spacetime, time, perpetual-motion

Suppose I trapped beryllium ions in a circular magnetic field, the ions forms a ring pattern as same charge repels. It is claimed that the ring will rotate even when they are cooled to almost absolute zero! Meaning there is a motion in time dimension and no energy is required thus creating perpetual machine... I know this is very wrong but please help me to understand the concept of movement in time dimension using analogy or plain english. I'm growing crystal for my science project and I have to understand relativity to do so pls help.

[Space-time crystal](http://futurism.com/loopholes-in-the-laws-of-physics-can-time-crystals-actually-exist/)

Comment: "It is claimed ..." ... by whom? A citation or link would help us to understand what you're thinking about.

Comment: @rob: I'd included the link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this but I'm curious about it too. Let's discuss.

First of all I don't understand why there will be a motion in time dimension. Am I missing something here?

Second, I don't think this ring can rotate indefinitely(do you have a source to confirm this?). I think it will lose energy by radiating EM waves. The rotational motion can only be accounted for by the minute thermal vibrations even at low temperatures.

The only thing close to a perpetual motion is current in a superconductor which when started lasts really really long. But that's an entirely different mechanism(correlated electron systems; BCS theory).

But let me remind you about Goldstone modes. These are modes that can be activated with almost no energy. You could read it up and maybe you'll find an answer to your question there.